# Bash Stopped Working - Possibly After XCode Install?

Tags: xcode, bash, terminal

In Terminal I get zero commands to work:

```
-bash: ls: command not found

-bash: sudo: command not found
```

Any ideas? I think this happened after installing XCode but I'm not certain.

OS X Lion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited .bash_profile (which was empty) and added this:

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"
```

It appears to be working again. Not sure how that happened.